# What is the efficiency of NTFS Junctions?

Tags: filesystems, symbolic-link, ntfs, hard-drive, inode

Long story short, I am using the [steamtool](http://www.stefanjones.ca/steam/) application, which was originally developed for the following reasons:

- Steam by default would save all your games to C:\
- SSDs are becoming the new primary drive for gamers
- This app will use an NTFS junction to create nothing but links from the SSD, to a larger, slower magnetic secondary drive, thereby saving space, but Steam will think the files are still located in the default directory on C:\

Sounds all fine and everything, and today Steam will now let you choose a secondary drive manually, but I want to use the tool for a "backwards" purpose:

- **I want to create an NTFS junction from my slower magnetic drive to my faster SSD to load my games faster**
- I would only keep 1 or 2 games on the SSD at a time, and I'm not worried about the NAND write cycles.

With only a basic understanding of inodes and those types of structures, my question is whether I will actually get any performance increase by creating an NTFS Junction from my magnetic drive to my SSD, or since all accesses go to the magnetic drive first, I won't get any increase.

Comment: As a side-note, I'm not asking if the tool is capable, just whether it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

Steam no longer requires you to install games on C: (or whichever is your steam installation path), you can pick any drive and create another library there. You can have multiple libraries, for different games.

[image]

Even though it does not answer your question, it probably addresses your original issue.

Comment: This doesn't work for all games though. For example the older source games don't as they share resources.

Comment: @DavidC.Bishop: You are right, I did not realise that. I was prompted to select a library for Warhammer before downloading, but there is no prompt for Half Life 2. Interesting...